How to get rid of an oven flue in my kitchen wall
I have this hole in the wall, presumably for some very old and outdated oven vent. I uncovered some of the wiring and discovered that it was hooked up to the electrical circuit... in the wall.
I'm glad that's not a fire hazard anymore, but it seems like a lot of moisture is getting through this area in addition to it being an unusable eyesore. What would be the best way to remove this?
I can't access the vent from the outside so I'd have to do everything from within. My not brilliant idea was going to be just to take an angle grinder to it but I'm concerned about the surrounding area.


Also the previous owner had stuck two shirts in there with some cardboard and caulked it. I intend to add some foam around it and other safeguards.

Picture of the exterior. There is no way to access it without risking great bodily harm.
To clarify, I would rather cut the cast iron flue down to a size that would fit behind the drywall because as it is, it is partially sticking through the wall.

Vents like these go to the outside.  Why can't you access from the outside?  If you are not going to remove the entire vent and exterior cover, just fill it with insulation and move on.

Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to cut the duct? How to patch the wall? Please revise to explain what specific aspect of the project is challenging you.

What is the source of the moisture?  I wouldn't close something up if it was still getting moisture.

And you'll need to do something with that wire, you can't just tuck it behind the drywall and cover it. You'll need to either trace it back to where it connects in the circuit and disconnect it there, or else put the end inside a junction box and keep the junction box accessible.

The exterior where the vent is located is above a cliff that would be stupidly dangerous to try to work around.

@user234935 people fitted the gutters and the vent previously so safe working is possible...

Looks like a through-the-wall fan housing, not an oven part.
If you can't do the work outside then don't remove it.
Assuming the exterior parts are intact, consider cutting a round plug of sheathing and cover it with housewrap.  Remove the shirts and cardboard.  Then insert the plug as far as possible and caulk around the edges.
As for cosmetic issues, maybe cover it with a wall hanging, but we can't see the context of this location in the photos.  If that's where the oven goes, a sheet of drywall with a framed tile backsplash would look nice.

It is installed at an angle so one side is behind the drywall but the other side is flush with the drywall. I would like to install a microwave in this area but having this jutting out would make things difficult. It was previously covered by a bit of back splash and adhesive.
